# Does document.createElement keep triggering DOMContentLoaded event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When I run this script, the page is continuously loading and eventually freezes. Is this because everytime I create an element, the main `DOMContentLoaded` listener is being called?

If so, how can I stop this recursive behaviour and just add one node to every pre existing node?

```
//Waits for page to load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  //Get all elements
    var items = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

    //Loop through entire DOM
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

        //If it is not a text node
        if (!(items[i].nodeType == 3)){

          //Create a div
          var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

          //Add div to current object
          items[i].appendChild(newDiv);
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `items` is referencing a "live list". This means that any updates to the DOM are going to be reflected in your list if they match the original selector.

Because you're appending a `div`, and your selector selects all elements, it gets added to the list, pushing any subsequent members up an index, and so the iteration continues.

To avoid this, make a non-live copy of the collection before iterating.

```
var items = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("*"));
```

---

And FYI, the `if (!(items[i].nodeType == 3)){` can be removed because `getElementsByTagName` will never return text nodes.

If you're supporting very old versions of IE, you may want to check that the `.nodeType === 1`, since some of those old versions included comment nodes when using `"*"`.

---

Lastly, you can use modern features to clean this up a bit.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    for (const el of [...document.getElementsByTagName("*")]) {
      var newDiv = el.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));

      // Work with newDiv
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow awesome, works perfectly! 

How does line 2 work? How did it get rid of the "live" problem?

Comment: @EricNelson: Glad it helped. The `Array.from()` is simply a utility that converts any array-like object to an actual array, which doesn't have the "live" characteristics. The `[...collection]` syntax is similar. It's just the array literal syntax but uses the `...` spread syntax to copy the collection into the array being created.

Answer (score 0):

You get a continuously loading page because you have this:

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

Which returns a **["live" node list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)** - meaning a list that can/will change as the matched elements change. Since your selector is for everything and then you create new elements, the set of matched elements changes (it gets bigger). Which, in turn causes the length of the node list to change, which keeps your loop running.

You should not try to match all the elements or you should use another method for getting the elements that doesn't return a live node list, like `querySelectoAll()`